# make: *** No rule to make target 'build-x86_64'. Stop. error in my OS when i run make build-x86_64

Tags: makefile

```
x86_64_asm_source_files := $(shell find src/impl/x86_64 -name *.asm)
x86_64_asm_object_files := $(patsubst src/impl/x86_64/%.asm, build/x86_64/%.o, $(x86_64_asm_source_files))

$(x86_64_asm_object_files): build/x86_64/%.o : src/impl/x86_64/%.asm
    mkdir -p $(dir $@) && \
    nasm -f elf64 $(patsubst build/x86_64/%.o, src/impl/x86_64/%.asm, $@) -o $@

.PHONY: build-x86_64
build-x86_64: $(x86_64_asm_object_files)
    mkdir -p dist/x86_64 && \
    x86_64-elf-ld -n -o dist/x86_64/kernel.bin -T targets/x86_64/linker.ld $(x86_64_asm_object_files) && \
    cp dist/x86_64/kernel.bin targets/x86_64/iso/boot/kernel.bin && \
    grub-mkrescue /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc -o dist/x86_64/kernel.iso targets/x86_64/iso
```

Comment: Click the [edit] link and fix your formatting using the code button. Also make sure you have proper indentation in your actual makefile.

Comment: There's little we can say with the info here.  If you get this error than make is clearly not using this makefile.  Please show the name of the makefile, and cut and paste the exact make command you invoked and the exact error you got (with proper formatting) into your question.